# how laravel helpers method should interact with database from view?

Tags: view, laravel, helper

In my view I list on the flow table rows from parsed xml which contains a specific mysql table ID and I would like to use it to count existing rows in my table.
How would I use a helper function in laravel view which expect this id and return counted rows?

something like

```
@foreach ($items as $item)

counted:{{count_rows($item->id)}}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this kind of calculations in your view, this is something your models should be doing, or, maybe, you controller. This is an example:

```
class Billing extends Controller {

    public function show($id)
    {
        $billing = Billing::find($id);

        return View::make('billing.show')->with('billing', $billing->getAllWithItems())
    }

}

class Billing extends Eloquent {

    public function getAllWithItems() 
    {
        return DB::table('billing')
            ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(items.id) as item_count')))
            ->left_join('items', 'items.billing_id', '=', 'billing.id')
            ->group_by('items.id')
            ->get();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback I re-factorized my codes and I bind everything inside of a a model. One thing what I do not really like my html redundant s.

Comment: Nice! If you are building a big app, think about using the repository pattern too, no domain related code in your models, just what's related to the database access.